# Is there a way to access an embedded template variable with PHP?

Tags: ee2, php

Is there a way to access an embedded template variable with PHP? I thought maybe it'd be in the $_GET or $_POST var, but no such luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of embed_vars can be accessed this way on EECMS 2.5.5-:

```
$this->EE->TMPL->embed_vars
```

And this way on EECMS 2.6+:

```
ee()->TMPL->embed_vars
```

Use "embed:var_name" as the array key.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more description on what you are trying to accomplish?

My immediate guess from what you have told us would be to use something like [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) and create a global variable then parse your php after EE to allow the variable you need to be available for php parsing.

Comment: I've got say: `{embed="temp_dir/temp" var="newVar"}` and in temp_dir/temp I have no EE, only PHP. With EE tags, I'd simply call `{embed:newVar}` and get the embedded data I passed. In saying that I think I answered my own question. I could flip parse order and store the embedded var as a PHP var.

`$newVar = '{embed:newVar}';`